# Software audio problem

Tags: audio

How I can turn the sound on my ViewSonic 19 LCD screen. I know the volume control on the
task bar, is all the way up. But the sound coming from the speakers is very low

Comment: Do you have a separate control on the screen for audio? What happens if you plug in a set of real speakers with a separate volume control? Have you tried boosting the volume using the settings in Control Panel? I assume you're on Windows here.

Answer (score 0):

My Viewsonics have a volume control included in the monitor OSD menu. Check there.